# Java: I'm stuck on singleton factories, and want to evolve my approach

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, factory

So, this is a pretty high-level question, addressing how I've been doing things for years. I know my approach can be improved, and I'm looking for a (or "the") correct / better way to generate factories.

For quite a while now, my brain has been stuck writing singleton factories. Here's the basic pseudo code of a factory:

```
public Factory { 
     private static final INSTANCE = new Factory();

     private Factory () {}

     public static Factory instance() { 
         return INSTANCE;
     }        

     public Object createStuff() {
        // impl specific factory details here
        return null;
     }
 }
```

Now, this approach allows me to be really lazy elsewhere in the code, not having to maintain instances of factories everywhere. I've recently stepped up my unit testing game though, and have run into problems mocking off the factories for testing purposes, which led me to question my approach.

I've heard dependency injection might be a good way to go, and I'm willing to investigate it. Some of my current projects are already too far down the road to adjust and introduce new approaches (so, no dependency injection in existing stuff).

So, bottom line: what's a better way to do this, both with and without dependency injection?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: dependency injection is using singleton, you just simply need to use frameworks like Spring so that you don't have to create your own Singleton class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to use DI and to have your classes which depend on your factories be testable you need to make your factories implement an interface, then have the classes which use the factories require an instance of the factory in the constructor of those classes. This will then let you test those classes by providing a stub or mock factory which also implments the interface.

Something like this

```
public interface IFactory
{
    object createInstance;
}

public class ClassWithDependencyOnFactory
{
     private IFactory factory;
     public ClassWithDependencyOnFactory(IFactory factory)
     {
        this.factory = factory;
     }

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         var thing = factory.createInstance();
         ...
     }
}
```

do not assume that you need to use a IoC framework (like Spring) in order to do DI or to get the benefits of the decoupling that it brings.

Comment: The introduction of new dependencies was really my concern (and why I'm shying away from things like Spring in my legacy apps). Good to know that I can investigate DI w/o extra frameworks.

Comment: i would start reading Mark seemans older posts on it. Checkout [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) and others it links to

Answer (score 0):

Have you heart about Spring (with Spring Boot)?

It starting to be de-facto standard for lightweight Java applications. 
It can significantly amount of code you need to developer full-reatured production application.

Comment: I've heard of Spring, but haven't really had a chance to play around with it. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I would get your head around DI first, and look at frameworks for helping to automate it later if things start to get overly complicated. Grokking DI as a concept and implementing it does not require a IoC framework

Comment: Do you consider Spring Guides too complicated?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't even had a chance to look at them. I'm sure they're perfectly understandable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that previous comment was targeted to @SamHolder

Comment: @lkrnac no its not that I think they are too complicated, just that many people confuse [pure di](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) with IoC frameworks, and think that it is not possible to do DI without an IoC framework like spring. In truth its usually easy to do DI without a framework, which can often hide how things work and lead to confusion as to how objects graphs have been constructed, and thinking that things are happening 'by magic'. IMHO its better to understand DI as a concept first, *then* look at IoC frameworks for helping with the object graph construction.

Comment: @SamHolder, I don't think DI concept is hard to grasp. Also the question was about enhancing the current approach. Do you believe that using DI without IoC Framework has any practical usage?

Comment: @lkrnac great, I'm glad you find it simple. I don't believe that this is the case for evreyone though (as witnessed by the number of questions on SO about it). And yes I think that DI should be used in most situations, but not all situations require an IoC framework. Unit tests is an example where often you don't need the overhead of an IoC framework, as are small projects or large projects that are composed of many small services. See [this article](http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/)

Comment: @lkrnac plus I've seen a lot of people use the container outside of the compositions root, which indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of DI and how containers should be used in the context of DI, and so I was recommending researching DI and getting a fundamental grasp on that first, before muddying the waters with adding in everything that a IoC container can bring to the table. Also [see this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) Do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: @SamHolder, I think this conversation is not productive. I would personally never use DI without IoC container (apart from unit test you mentioned). If you are not using framework you are creating one. Also I think that if you are OO developer aware of polymorphism, grasp DI should very simple.

Comment: @lkrnac to do pure DI you wouldn't need to create a framework, just use the `new` keyword a lot in the composition root. And I think you are being generous to a lot of the people asking questions on here to suggest the grasping DI should be 'very simple'

Comment: @SamHolder, I hope you don't mind if I wouldn't continue this conversation.